# Ubuntu 14.04: `apt-get update` failed, no `unity_revamped` for Trusty

Tags: unity, apt, updates, ppa

`sudo apt-get update` gives:

```
Get:83 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4089 kB]   
Fetched 31.9 MB in 15s (2073 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ikarosdev/unity-revamped/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ikarosdev/unity-revamped/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have looked at that address and only precise is available.

I have tried:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64+mac (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` using

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

search PPA file that is related to `ikarosdev/unity-revamped` and detete that then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

404 error comes when that web page not available there. PPA that you using is only for Ubuntu precise version . there is no trusty version. you can verify by going that link :[see here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ikarosdev/unity-revamped/ubuntu/dists/)

Comment: True. As one can see on the [corresponding launchpad website](https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/+archive/ubuntu/unity-revamped), the PPA only holds binaries compiled for Precise (12.04), not for Trusty (14.04) which you request. You have to look for a different PPA if you need this package.

Comment: Thanks.   I am not sure how the unity_revamped file got in there.

Comment: you have added ppa to install unity earlier . it might be it was working that time but now maintainer removed for trusty version.  but any way your problem is solved . :)-

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PPA by the commands below, there are no Trusty packages

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped
```

The command disables a PPA and reverts to official packages.

---

Now start

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again.